# Создать список со всевозможными комбинациями букв алфавита

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть [английский алфавит](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/complete-english-alphabet-collage-26-600w-90630052.jpg)
Я хочу создать все трёхбуквенные и четырёхбуквенные комбинации на основе этого алфавита.

```
In [3]: list(permutations(['a', 'b', 'c']))                                          
Out[3]: 
[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой: я не понимаю, как положить в `list(permutations([]))` этот список уникальных трёх или четырёх букв.
Есть идеи, как это реализовать?
Спасибо!

Comment: добавить в функцию через запятую дополнительный параметр 3 или 4

Comment: В таких случаях обычно помогает чтение документации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

# Импортируем алфавит из стандартной библиотеки, чтобы не набивать его вручную
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet


result = list(chain(
                    permutations(alphabet, 3),
                    permutations(alphabet, 4),
                    ))
```